# Hystrix only executes the fallbackMethod the first time the error occurs

Tags: java, spring, microservices, hystrix

I'm trying to a little script using the Spring framework that creates a "note" for a "user" on a "Notes" microservice.

Then there is a "Users" microservice that is independent and in order to create the note for the user, I should first check if that user exists in the "Users" microservice.

However, if the "User" microservice is down I want to store that note in a map (along with the username) and then, every 10 seconds, retry to create it.

I expected the Hystrix to perform exactly the same way every time that the method with the @HystrixCommand tag is executed but the first time it does while the second it does not.

The Hystrix does not handle the error if the "Users" microservice remains down the second time the "createUserNote" method is called.

```
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "createUserNoteReliable")
public NoteLab createUserNote(String username, NoteLab noteLab) {

    System.out.println("Trying to create user note (HystrixCommand)");

    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/users/userExists/" + username);

    System.out.println("uri created");

    if (restTemplate.getForObject(uri, boolean.class)) {
        System.out.println("CREATING NOTE " +noteLab.getId());
        try {
            noteLab.setDateCreation(LocalDateTime.now());
            noteLab.setDateEdit(LocalDateTime.now());
            return addUserNote(username, noteLab);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("User " +username + " does not exist");
        return null;
    }

}

HashMap<NoteLab, String> mapNoteUser = new HashMap<>();

public NoteLab createUserNoteReliable(String username, NoteLab noteLab) {
    System.out.println("User server is down. Saving the note " +noteLab.getId());
    try {
        mapNoteUser.put(noteLab, username);
    } catch (Exception e){}
    return null;
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) //In miliseconds. (10s)
public void retryCreateUserNote(){
    System.out.println("Executing automatic retry method");

    for( NoteLab note:  mapNoteUser.keySet() ) {
        System.out.println("Retying to create note " + note.toString() + " from " + mapNoteUser.get(note));

        NoteLab noteToRetry = note;
        String userToRetry = mapNoteUser.get(note);

        mapNoteUser.remove(note);

        createUserNote(userToRetry, noteToRetry);
    }
}
```

I leave my code here and any clue about what's happening would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How did you test the code? How many times did you call `createUserNote`? Can you add your test code as well?

Comment: This is my testing code in a @RestController class in the Notes microservice: https://i.imgur.com/xlo5bhd.png

I just go to the desired URL and that's all. The createUserNote method tries to check the user, it fails and the Hystrix calls the createUserNoteReliable method which adds the note and the user to a map. Every 10 seconds the retryCreateUserNote method is called and deletes the map entry for each user-note and then calls the createUserNote method again to execute the same process as if it were a petition from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand how annotations work. The annotation is only used from **outside** the class.
The annotation `@HystrixCommand` will wrap your object to handle all calls from outside.

But when you call the `createUserNote` method from the `retryCreateUserNote` method, this is an **inside** operation. This method call will not pass through the wrapper object!

That is why you only see it being called once.

I hope this clarifies what is happening!

Comment: So... if I want use the Hystrix more than once I have to create a different class, call a method in it and then call the method with the Hystrix annotation in the "original" class from the new class?
It seems odd to me. Isn't there any other solution? (just curiosity)

Comment: Please notice that the 'Circuit Breaker'-pattern of Hystrix is the complete opposite of the Retry-pattern. They both want to tackle problems, but differently. Choosing retry in a fallback method, is not what Hystrix is created for. Hystrix wants to give the other server some **time to recover** from heavy load. Retry is putting **more load** on the other server